# Stock Chart values on the y axis are being rounded

Tags: anychart

I have a chart that I am displaying but the values on the y axis are being rounded to 1 decimal place but I would like for it to go to 2 decimal places. The data being fed into the chart has 6 decimal places as you can see in the legend when you hover over different parts of the chart. How do I keep it from rounding or specifying the number of decimals to round to? I have included a sample of the data because the full set is over a 1000 lines long. The full data set is in the codepen.

Thanks

https://codepen.io/akrug23/pen/dyXjYdO

```
let data = {
  count: 226,
  results: [
    { date: "2019-12-12", nav_code: "2039", amount: "10.000000", change: 0 },
    { date: "2019-12-13", nav_code: "2039", amount: "10.000000", change: 0 },
    {
      date: "2019-12-16",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.208000",
      change: 2.037618
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-17",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.236000",
      change: 2.305588
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-18",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.248000",
      change: 2.419984
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-19",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.264000",
      change: 2.572097
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-20",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.284000",
      change: 2.761571
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-23",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.292000",
      change: 2.837155
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-24",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.292000",
      change: 2.837155
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-26",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.312000",
      change: 3.025601
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-27",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.324000",
      change: 3.138318
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-30",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.300000",
      change: 2.912621
    },
    {
      date: "2019-12-31",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.316000",
      change: 3.063203
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-02",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.368000",
      change: 3.549383
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-03",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.350799",
      change: 3.389101
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-06",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.339216",
      change: 3.280868
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-07",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.328300",
      change: 3.178645
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-08",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.339970",
      change: 3.287921
    },
    {
      date: "2020-01-09",
      nav_code: "2039",
      amount: "10.386636",
      change: 3.722437
     }
  ]
};

function createStockChart(chartContainerID, rangeContainerID, data) {
  var percentageChange = anychart.data.table("date");
  percentageChange.addData(data);

  var navs = anychart.data.table("date");
  navs.addData(data);

  // Init stock chart
  var chart = anychart.stock();

  //Set animations
  chart.animation(true, 5000);

  //Remove the credits
  chart.credits().enabled(false);

  //Set chart settings
  var plot = chart.plot();
  plot
    .line()
    .data(
      percentageChange.mapAs({
        value: "change"
      })
    )
    .name("% Change")
    .fill("#99328e")
    .stroke("#99328e")
    .tooltip(false);
  
  plot.yAxis().labels().format(function() {
    return this.value.toFixed(2);
  });

  chart.crosshair(true);
  chart.crosshair().yLabel().format(function() {
    return this.value.toFixed(2);
  });
  
  
  //format the legend
  var legend = plot.legend();

  //enable legend
  legend.enabled(true);

  //remove the title
  legend.titleFormat(false);

  //format item in legend
  legend.useHtml(true);
  legend.itemsFormat("% Change: {%value}");

  //Disable the scroller
  chart.scroller().enabled(false);

  //Set container for chart and draw chart
  chart.container(chartContainerID);
  chart.draw();
}

createStockChart("stock-chart", "stock-chart-range-selector", data.results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it! In the context of the crosshair label formatter you can find `rawValue` field that includes not rounded value. You should use it for this purpose, instead of `value` field. Like this:

```
chart.crosshair().yLabel().format(function() {
  console.log(this.rawValue);
  return this.rawValue;
});
```

So, you can round or format the raw value exactly as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` value is in the range 0 - 4 in the data sample you provided. So, the chart shows ticks and labels on the yAxis [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5]. The chart tends to show nice rounded ticks in this case. There's no need to show 6 digits if you are about to show ticks value `3` or `1.5`. The yAxis labels formatter function will include not rounded values if your data range will be like 2.111111 - 2.111122. Then it will make sense to show all 6 digits to demonstrate ticks in this range.
Anyway, if you really need to show a specific set of ticks, you can apply them manually using [ticks() function](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Linear#ticks).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have a problem with the ticks on the y axis being rounded. But I am trying to round the y axis labels in the crosshairs that are displayed when you hover your mouse over the chart. I have tried to use the format function but the value coming into that function is already rounded like the ticks are on the y axis. Here is my code for the crosshairs label
`chart.crosshair(true);
  chart.crosshair().yLabel().format(function() {
    return this.value.toFixed(2);
  });`